# Getting a Sum and Count from Different Tables

Tags: mysql, report

I'm guessing this is too local but I can't figure out a way to make it more general (which might be why I'm not able to find my answer on Google).

We have an application that tracks contacts for our business.  These contacts (Contact table) are either contacted through the phone (Contact_Phone table) or through email (Contact_Email).  If the user is contacted through the phone an agent keeps track of the total number of seconds (Contact_Phone.totalSeconds).   Through a piece of business logic that I have no control over email contacts are treated as one second.  A user might be contact through just email, just phone, or both.

I'm trying to generate a report on how long we've spent contacting each user but I can't get the results I expect.

Tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Contact` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Contact_Email` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ContactId` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `contact_email_contact_idx` (`ContactId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `contact_email_contact`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ContactId` )
    REFERENCES `Contact` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Contact_Phone` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `totalSeconds` INT NULL ,
  `ContactId` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `Contact_Phone_contact_idx` (`ContactId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `Contact_Phone_contact`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ContactId` )
    REFERENCES `Contact` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Test Data:

```
insert into Contact (id, name) values (1, 'Scott');
insert into Contact (id, name) values (2, 'Joe');

insert into Contact_Phone (totalSeconds, ContactId) values (10, 2);
insert into Contact_Phone (totalSeconds, ContactId) values (100, 2);

insert into Contact_Email (ContactId) values (1);
insert into Contact_Email (ContactId) values (1);
insert into Contact_Email (ContactId) values (2);
```

Query:

```
select 
name,
    (select sum(totalSeconds) from Contact_Phone where Contact_Phone.ContactId = Contact.id) 
    + 
    (select count(*) from Contact_Email where Contact_Email.ContactId = Contact.id)
from Contact;
```

Expected Results:

```
Joe    111
Scott  2
```

Actual Results:

```
Joe    111
Scott  null
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you run a query that returns three columns and expect results to only have two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using summaries and LEFT JOIN operations, like so?

```
SELECT Contact.name,
       COALESCE(p.seconds,0) + COALESCE(e.seconds,0) seconds
  FROM Contact.Name
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT ContactID AS id,
                     SUM(totalSeconds) AS seconds
                FROM ContactPhone
               GROUP BY ContactID
             ) p  ON Contact.id = p.id
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT ContactID AS id,
                     COUNT(*) AS seconds
                FROM ContactEmail
               GROUP BY ContactID
             ) e  ON Contact.id = e.id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` operations will preserve your result rows where one or the other of your "seconds" computations is NULL. And, the COALESCE operations will prevent your query from attempting arithmetic on NULL values, which yields NULL.